# Why is nixos-rebuild switch creating a store for something that is not used?

Tags: nixos

I did something to my system when switching channels from `nixos-18.09` to `nixos-unstable` and back, and now run into an issue that prevents `$ nixos-rebuild switch` from running successfully.

When I try to do that, I get the following error:

```
writing manifest file 'singledispatch.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Copying singledispatch.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py3.6.egg-info
running install_scripts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nix_run_setup", line 8, in <module>
    exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\\r\\n', '\\n'), __file__, 'exec'))
  File "setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    long_description = f.read()
  File "/nix/store/qbyckcddc74s2fi060n8xqcn8gygrhjl-python3-3.6.8/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 898: ordinal not in range(128)
builder for '/nix/store/mcncvdwadrq1335bwy279dg7q0sxhvhp-python3.6-rsa-4.0.drv' failed with exit code 1
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/pifmbmqallj7jkl3ar1wv8nqyfzq08hr-python3.6-python-jose-3.0.1.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
building '/nix/store/1qy7ka8c0s3mjv51pdiyyp103d11awkb-python3.6-termstyle-0.1.11.drv'...
building '/nix/store/8zvlx7367p21vj0iccsvhpz1jv3wx0b6-python3.6-websocket_client-0.54.0.drv'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/3w08jzilgvddzx728nnkpaadc7sd9p2v-python3.6-moto-1.3.7.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
building '/nix/store/qfkfr913dx4ssp1qahfd9wcj6csf6yxm-python3.6-xlrd-1.1.0.drv'...
building '/nix/store/dvi6y2zlc4gwli0qqhxhr6cbvfs5qwhx-python3.6-xlwt-1.3.0.drv'...
building '/nix/store/p38p279r5y8bh7n9pvw8194k9zvnybic-reload-container.drv'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/sf4d3zrds99sq22s096f4pdwb2602mf2-python3.6-pandas-0.23.4.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
building '/nix/store/hy1197qj5ivb54wicyn0ljdbv8qxp0zc-remove-references-to.drv'...
building '/nix/store/6cqp8vf151gvxbnz03qp4sj9awd8lnfc-smb-dummy.conf.drv'...
building '/nix/store/cb5r8y9llx4yw64kyg2hhwds4g123h29-stage-1-init.sh.drv'...
building '/nix/store/4ps1704mhdqj5bp1ck7sa2x67l7h08x4-su.pam.drv'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/hx05mqxryfl1aqvc5lqf0q05n230qnz3-system-path.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
building '/nix/store/zrrbcfif92d7yz1d4vlcnva3gx8npc2k-systemd-boot-builder.py.drv'...
building '/nix/store/z8mld3scs2hzb6k3hffjqvfyrg9qnlg7-systemd-user.pam.drv'...
building '/nix/store/0gixkqfsr3plwcyf72izycpkr5rf1r6k-udev-rules.drv'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/19sp5z5i8kg7x0inyrb1kzm1n6g6rzcc-nixos-system-nixos-19.03pre164715.201d739b0ff.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/19sp5z5i8kg7x0inyrb1kzm1n6g6rzcc-nixos-system-nixos-19.03pre164715.201d739b0ff.drv' failed
```

I have tried removing the offending path by running

```
$ nix-store --delete /nix/store/19sp5z5i8kg7x0inyrb1kzm1n6g6rzcc-nixos-system-nixos-19.03pre164715.201d739b0ff.drv
```

That path has no 'referrers' according to

```
$ nix-store -q --referrers /nix/store/19sp5z5i8kg7x0inyrb1kzm1n6g6rzcc-nixos-system-nixos-19.03pre164715.201d739b0ff.drv`)
```

I also garbage-collected using `$ nix-store --gc`. However, running `$ nixos-rebuild switch` still re-creates this path and gives the same error again.

Why is `$ nixos-rebuild switch` creating this path, and how can I get that command running successfully again?

I am not sure why `nixos-system-nixos-19.03` is present on my system at all; at this point I am only tracking the `nixos-18.09` channel:

```
$ nixos-channel --list
nixos-18.09 https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-18.09
```

Comment: If no build ever succeeded, then nothing that depends on it will have succeeded and thus have had a gc root created, so yeah, `nix-store --gc` won't know anything about it.

Comment: `nix show-derivation -r /nix/store/19sp5z5i8kg7x0inyrb1kzm1n6g6rzcc-nixos-system-nixos-19.03pre164715.201d739b0ff.drv` is your friend -- it'll have everything needed to track this down.

Comment: ...or, if you want something in graphical form, `nix-store -q --graph /nix/store/19sp5z5i8kg7x0inyrb1kzm1n6g6rzcc-nixos-system-nixos-19.03pre164715.201d739b0ff.drv` is probably a good place to start.

Comment: That said, your error message is also pretty clear about what the dependency chain is. Your system is configured to have a Python 3 with `pandas` in the default PATH. `pandas` depends on `moto`, which depends on `python-jose`, which depends on `rsa`, which is what failed.

Comment: BTW, where does that `nixos-channel` command come from? `nix-channel --list` I'm familiar with; `nixos-channel --list`, not as much so. And if you want to check your nix channels as pertinent to `nixos-rebuild`, be sure you look at the ones configured for root, not your user account; thus, `sudo nix-channel --list` is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you filter through the error message, it's pretty clear about the chain of events:

```
builder for '/nix/store/mcncvdwadrq1335bwy279dg7q0sxhvhp-python3.6-rsa-4.0.drv' failed with exit code 1
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/pifmbmqallj7jkl3ar1wv8nqyfzq08hr-python3.6-python-jose-3.0.1.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/3w08jzilgvddzx728nnkpaadc7sd9p2v-python3.6-moto-1.3.7.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/sf4d3zrds99sq22s096f4pdwb2602mf2-python3.6-pandas-0.23.4.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/hx05mqxryfl1aqvc5lqf0q05n230qnz3-system-path.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/19sp5z5i8kg7x0inyrb1kzm1n6g6rzcc-nixos-system-nixos-19.03pre164715.201d739b0ff.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/19sp5z5i8kg7x0inyrb1kzm1n6g6rzcc-nixos-system-nixos-19.03pre164715.201d739b0ff.drv' failed
```

So, the build of the Python `rsa` module failed because that package has a bug.

Why do we depend on `rsa`? Because...

- Your system is configured to have a Python 3.6 install with `pandas` in its default PATH.
- `pandas` depends on the package `moto` to run its tests ([`pkgs/development/python-modules/pandas/default.nix:38`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/d38f1035862884c4ba84244928557b05e607be02/pkgs/development/python-modules/pandas/default.nix#L38)).
- The `moto` package depends on `python-jose` ([`pkgs/development/python-modules/moto/default.nix:44`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/d38f1035862884c4ba84244928557b05e607be02/pkgs/development/python-modules/moto/default.nix#L44)).
- The `python-jose` package depends on the `rsa` package ([`pkgs/development/python-modules/python-jose/default.nix:33`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/d38f1035862884c4ba84244928557b05e607be02/pkgs/development/python-modules/python-jose/default.nix#L33)).

---

BTW, while this is the case on nixpkgs-unstable, the 18.09 release (latest published as of this answer) doesn't have this dependency from `python-jose` on `rsa`, and so doesn't exhibit the issue at hand. Might I suggest using it instead?